# Local notification add/delete for a single item in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, apple-push-notifications

Hello I would like to create a local notification manager for my application, my entity is created with a title, a button if the item is finished or not, a date picker and also a boolean if a date is created otherwise nil, to create a notification all is well.
But if for example today it is June 1, 2022, I create an item for June 5, 2022, no worries so far but my come if in the meantime I finish my item, the notification is still active and I don’t understand how the identify UUID in string works…

Here is my code below, but when I call the cancelNotification function in another view I don't understand what to put exactly, item.id, uuid, identifier?....
I'm new to programming, thanks

```
func pushNotification(input:Date,text:String){
     
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: input)
    let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: input)
    let second = calendar.component(.second, from: input)
    let day = calendar.component(.day, from: input)
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: input)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Organized"
    content.subtitle = text
    content.sound = .default
    content.badge = 1
    
    var dateC=DateComponents()
    
    dateC.hour=hour
    dateC.minute=minute
    dateC.second=second
    dateC.month=month
    dateC.day=day
    
    
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateC, repeats: false)
    
    let requst = UNNotificationRequest(
        identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content,trigger: trigger
    )
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requst)
}

func cancelNotification(ids: [String]) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ids)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: ids)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a static string identifier for the cancel to work; change the lines:

```swift
let requst = UNNotificationRequest(
    identifier: "NotificationIdentifier", content: content,trigger: trigger
)
```

And when you want to cancel all notifications, you can do this:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```

If you have multiple notifications and want to cancel a specific notification, you can use this:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { (notificationRequests) in
   var identifiers: [String] = []
   for notification:UNNotificationRequest in notificationRequests {
       if notification.identifier == "NotificationIdentifier" {
          identifiers.append(notification.identifier)
       }
   }
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: identifiers)
}
```

or simply:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: "NotificationIdentifier")
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your quick response! So even by just writing "NotificationIdentifier" my notification remains unique to an item? don't need a UUID or have one in my attributes entity?

Comment: You can have the UUID-based approach too, but you would need to store it somewhere on the device. For the first part of your question, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103143/swift-multiple-local-notifications-but-only-show-latest).

Comment: Yes I just tried what you told me but it only affects one notification, I need to be able to have several and therefore I think I have a different identifier but I don't see how to do it

Comment: For every notification, you would need to create a UUID and store them, and when you want to modify or delete them, you can access the UUIDs. CoreData might me a  possible solution

Comment: Update: I did what you told me, for each new entry I assigned a UUID and everything seems to work! Thanks